# Why is the target property of the mousewheel event different from that of other (click, mousedown, touchstart) events?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

The mousewheel event's `target` property provides the DOM element that the mouse is currently hovering over as the mousewheel (or gesture-capable touchpad) is being operated.

When I do this (at least in Safari 6, I will test other browsers later) I will get the text node itself as `target`.

This never happens with other events which always produce a non text node even if I perform the action directly over text.

Needless to say it makes the code more complex than otherwise.

Is there a reason for this? I'd like to avoid having to check the parent node, though thankfully the nice thing about this situation is that I would only ever need to check the `target` node's parent.

I can't decide if this is a feature or a bug.

Comment: seems to happen only in Chrome/Safari .. here's a jsfiddle which I used to test this http://jsfiddle.net/sbrjL/ .. interestingly if you do a mousewheel on the padding of the div (or anywhere with no text) it will return the element as a target .. could you use `this` keyword instead of `event.target` ?

Comment: This is normalized by jQuery because of "a Safari bug".

Comment: @pimvdb if you dig up the source that indicates that i'll accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's [a snippet](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/97fa97f0c1cd6a14a0d7f5e2599b30c502bd3e8c/src/event.js#L491) of the jQuery code where they normalize this behaviour because it's a bug:

```
// Target should not be a text node (#504, Safari)
if ( event.target.nodeType === 3 ) {
    event.target = event.target.parentNode;
}
```