# Get the element (node) which triggered an event

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to find the element which was listening for the event which triggered the current function?

In the code below, `event.target` is returning the lowest child node of `#xScrollPane` and `event.currentTarget` and `event.fromElement` are both null. Is there some other way to retrieve a DOM reference to `#xScrollPane` without hard coding it?

```
//convert vertical scroll wheel to horizontal scroll wheel:
function scrollWheelX(event) {
    if (event.deltaY == 0) return
    event.target.scroll(event.target.scrollLeft + event.deltaY * 5, event.target.scrollTop)
    event.preventDefault()
}
document.getElementById('xScrollPane').addEventListener('wheel', scrollWheelX)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the target property of the mousewheel event different from that of other (click, mousedown, touchstart) events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109763/why-is-the-target-property-of-the-mousewheel-event-different-from-that-of-other)

Comment: The answer there is quite bare. Are they saying it's a webkit bug with mousewheel events? it can't be solved with `event.target.parentNode` as this only works if the mouse is over a direct child of the scolled element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Inside the event handler, the `this` object refers to the element the event handler was added to.

In cases where `this` doesn't refer to the desired element or object, you can bind the element into the `this` object. Note that if you need to use `removeEventListener`, you have to pass the bound function to it instead of just the original function.

Example of binding even though in this case it wasn't necessary:

```
function scrollWheelX(event) {
    if(event.deltaY == 0) {
        return;
    }

    this.scroll(this.scrollLeft + event.deltaY * 5, this.scrollTop);
    event.preventDefault();
}

const scrollingElement = document.getElementById("scrollElement");
scrollingElement.addEventListener("wheel", scrollWheelX.bind(scrollingElement));
```

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, shouldn't `this` refer to the correct element even without binding?

Comment: Holy crap you're right! `this` works perfectly without binding. Thanks 

Comment: Great, I edited the answer to better suit your case.